Занести несколько элементов в список Python
Есть код, в котором нужно прочитать содержимое текстового документа в переменную и затем эту переменную разделить пробелом и каждый кусок поместить в отдельный элемент списка. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно это сделать, а то у меня что-то не получается. Код приложен ниже
AdresTxt=open('List/AdresList.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') 
AdresStr= [str(AdresTxt.read()).split()]
print(AdresStr[0])

По сути, программа должна вывести указанный элемент, но в строке вывода я получаю следующее:
['Element1' , 'Element2']
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить.

split уже делает то что вам нужно, а вы заносите массив в ещё 1 массив получая [['Element1', 'Element2']]. Правильный код AdresStr= AdresTxt.read().split()

Спасибо, попробую
